# How to catch HttpRequestValidationException in production

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5, iis-7.5, global-asax

I have this piece of code to handle the HttpRequestValidationException in my global.asax.cs file.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    var exception = context.Server.GetLastError();
    if (exception is HttpRequestValidationException)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.StatusCode = 200;
        Response.Write(@"<html><head></head><body>hello</body></html>");
        Response.End();
        return;
    }
}
```

If I debug my webapplication, it works perfect. But when i put it on our production-server, the server ignores it and generate the "*a potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client*" - error page.
I don't know what happens exactly...
If anybody knows what the problem is, or what i do wrong..?

Also I don't want to set the validaterequest on false in the web.config.

The server uses IIS7.5, And I'm using asp.net 3.5.

Thanks,
Bruno

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, i found it my self.
I must clear my last error.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    var exception = context.Server.GetLastError();
    if (exception is HttpRequestValidationException)
    {
        context.Server.ClearError();    // Here is the new line.
        Response.Clear();
        Response.StatusCode = 200;
        Response.Write(@"<html><head></head><body>hello</body></html>");
        Response.End();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need the "context" var. It works just fine as "Server.GetLastError()" and "Server.ClearError()".

Comment: Response.End() throws an exception by design. Instead use this:
`HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest`.

Take a look at this for the explanation: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/312629/prb-threadabortexception-occurs-if-you-use-response-end-response-redir

Comment: With the comments from @WildJoe and Kamran (sorry cannot notify both, thanks SO), this looks to be a very viable and useful way to override the default error handling in Web API. +1.

Answer (score 10):

Another way that only works with MVC is using a custom Exception Filter:

- Create a custom FilterAttribute that implements IExceptionFilter
- from inside the FilterAttribute, you can redirect to the controller or view to be used to display the error.
- register the filter in the Global.asax or attribute your controllers

This has the advantage that you can use the normal MVC infrastructure (Razor) to render the error view.

```
public class HttpRequestValidationExceptionAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter {

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) {
        if (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled && filterContext.Exception is HttpRequestValidationException) {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/HttpError/HttpRequestValidationError");
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing :-)
I'll look at it when I have some spare time :-)

Comment: Thanks for this.  I used it but found that filterContext.ExceptionHandled was already set to true so the code in the if statement wasn't run and my default error page was shown.  I took that condition out and it now appears to work perfectly.  Not sure if doing so might cause problems elsewhere though... any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: Testing for ExceptionHandled is done so a single exception is not handled by multiple filters.. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597478/exceptioncontext-exceptionhandled-changes-to-true-where-is-the-exception-being for further discussion.

Comment: this answer should be accepted. It is better to have filters than filter all exceptions in Global