# ExceptionContext.ExceptionHandled changes to true. Where is the exception being handled?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, exception, custom-error-pages

I'm using a global action filter to handle and log all exceptions.

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new ElmahHandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
```

This is how the global action filter `ElmahHandleErrorAttribute` is defined - it overrides the `OnException` method.

```
public class ElmahHandleErrorAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
       //Is the exception handled already? context.ExceptionHandled seems to be true here
        if (!context.IsChildAction && (context.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled))
        {
            //Do other stuff stuff
            //Log to Elmah               
        }
    }
   ...
 }
```

I don't understand why the value of `context.ExceptionHandled` is true when the `OnException` method executes.
How is this exception getting handled?

**-EDIT-**
I have a `customErrors` section in the `Web.Config`. I have an `ErrorController` class, and actions called `General` and `Http404`.

```
<customErrors mode ="On" defaultRedirect="Error/General">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Error/Http404"/>
  </customErrors>
```

*What I don't understand is, the controller action `General` is not executed (breakpoint is never hit), but the value of `ExceptionContext.ExceptionHandled` is set to true when the `OnException` method of `ElmahHandleErrorAttribute` starts executing.*

Comment: I can't see `context.ExceptionHandled` in your code, where is it?

Comment: @gdoron I removed the check for context.ExceptionHandled. It was earlier included in the statement: `if (!context.IsChildAction && !context.ExceptionHandled && (context.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled))`

Comment: Did you override the `OnException` method of the controller?

Comment: @gdoron: No I override the `OnException` method of the MVC `HandleErrorAttribute` filter.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When an exception occurs, the order of the global filters executes [in reverse order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28v=vs.98%29.aspx#sectionToggle4).  This means that `HandleErrorAttribute` runs first.

You can view the code of `HandleErrorAttribute` [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f2c3a69d7d92#src%2fSystem.Web.Mvc%2fHandleErrorAttribute.cs), but in short, it:

1. Only executes if `ExceptionHandled` is false, and custom errors are enabled.
2. Sets up a redirect to the error view, which by default is called `Error`.
3. **Sets `ExceptionHandled` to true.**

As it's the first filter, then `ExceptionHandled` is false when it executes, causing it to set the view to Error and setting `ExceptionHandled` to true. So, then, when your own filter executes, that is why `ExceptionHandled` is already set to true.  Note that if custom errors were disabled, then `ExceptionHandled` would still be false, as `HandleErrorAttribute` wouldn't have done its stuff.  In this case, ELMAH will log the error anyway, as it's unhandled (yellow screen of death), so the test in your class is to prevent duplicate logging of the error.

Now, on to your other question about whey the `General` action isn't executed, the `defaultRedirect` is only used if the filters don't set some explicit redirect themselves, so it's actually ignored when an exception occurs inside an ActionMethod and you have the global filter `HandleErrorAttribute` registered.  It would however, be called if you entered a URL that didn't exist, i.e. an error that doesn't occur from within an ActionMethod.  Also, if you comment out the line to register the `HandleErrorAttribute` in Global.asax.cs, then you'll always get the `General` controller action executing.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It really helped me. I want ElmahHandleErrorAttribute to be the first filter that executes. Would setting the order of this custom filter fix this? As per this comment (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9163926/1242061) I should give a higher Order value to the filter I want to execute first.

Comment: Yes, I suspect you could play around with the Order property (but not sure how do do that on a global filter, have only done this when using it as an attribute).
Simply reversing the order you add the filters in RegisterGlobalFilters should work ... when an error occurs, the one added last will run first.
Not sure why you would want the ELMAH one to run first though, and if you really do, you can't check for ExceptionHandled as it will always be false in that case.

Comment: I specified the orders when registering the filters. Now my custom filter `ElmahHandleErrorAttribute` is handling the error first. Regarding your question _Not sure why you would want the ELMAH one to run first though_, Do you think this is a bad idea? I'm doing this because I want to display custom error pages and check the error type and display a specific view.

Comment: Providing that the ELMAH view will always display a view, then yes, I think that's OK. However, if you leave the default `HandleErrorAttribute` to handle the fallback case, if *it* doesn't set a view either, then a YSOD occurs and you'll potentially end up with ELMAH logging the error twice (once in the global filter, and once when the exception isn't marked as handled).
If you're setting views in your ELMAH filter, then maybe you should get rid of the `HandleErrorAttribute` altogether?

Comment: I guess I should get rid of `HandleErrorAttribute`. The custom `ElmahHandleErrorAttribute` will display a view. Since I have defined Application_Error() in `global.asax` to handle 404 and other unhandled exceptions, I don't think a YSOD would be displayed.